# C# SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am working with a C# application connected to a SQL Server database. I've heard about security of data, so I decided to work with stored procedure in SQL Server.

My question is after I created stored procedures in SQL Server, is my code in C# secured or not to prevent SQL injection? Did I use the correct code?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = test; Integrated Security = true");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("selectdhena", con); // Using a Store Procedure.
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

DataTable dt = new DataTable("dtLista");
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", txt.Text); 

dtg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Yes, but please do not use AddWithValue. Use the proper Add with the SqlDbType and the expected size of the parameter

Comment: Could you give me a example, cause i am new to c#

Comment: There's no need to use stored procedures just to avoid SQL injection attacks - simply using parameterized SQL is fine.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you use correct code. Stored procedures is protected against injection attacks. Only if you using *EXEC* inside stored procedure for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUserTable
    @data systemData
AS
    EXEC('CREATE TABLE ' + @data + ' (column1 varchar(100), column2 varchar(100))');
GO
```

An attacker could inject into the application some code that sets the data to be

```
a(c1 int); SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;--
```

That would stop SQL Server. So inside your stored procedures better to have some check logic:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AlterUserTable
    @data systemData
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
              WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
                AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND TABLE_NAME = @data)
BEGIN
    // The table is known to exist
    // construct the appropriate command here
END
GO
```